# angular Material Data Table with Fixed footer with Paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material Table with fixed footer and header, and paginator. the problem is how i show the sum of rows data in footer. How rows data be calculated to show in footer .
[image]

`

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxHide fxShow.gt-sm mat-sort-header>Quantity</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchase" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
        <p class="font-weight-600 text-truncate">
            {{purchase.quantity}}
        </p>
    </mat-cell>
    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>

    </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxHide fxShow.gt-sm mat-sort-header>Price</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchase" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
        <p class="font-weight-600 text-truncate">
            {{purchase.price}}
        </p>
    </mat-cell>
    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>  </mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>


<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>

<mat-row *matRowDef="let purchase; columns: displayedColumns;" class="contact" (click)="editPurchase(purchase)"
    [ngClass]="{'accent-50':checkboxes[purchase._id]}" matRipple [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'100%'}}">
</mat-row>

<mat-footer-row mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-footer-row>
```

```
<mat-toolbar>
<mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-icon (click)="exportCsv(dataSource)" title="Export as CSV">save_alt</mat-icon>

    <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="dataSource.filteredData.length" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="10"
        [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
</mat-toolbar-row>
```

`

Comment: Please explain what problem are you facing and what are you trying to achieve

Comment: i'm facing problem how sum of rows data show in footer. in <mat-footer-cell> tag

Comment: Please post your component code too

Answer (score 0):

You can just reduce your prices array:

```
this.total = pricesArray.reduce((priceA, priceB) => {return priceA + priceB})
```

This will sum all your prices and will give you the total

Comment: it will some all the prices but how we get the page number wise data

Comment: For that you can use the array.slice() method https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice